8,000 btu portable air conditioner inadequate
I live in an area of high humidity. My windows are nailed down and there is just a blanket separating the living area from the kitchen. I have an8,000 btu ac unit, various blower fans & circulating fans, all strategically placed, but it's inadequate.
If I place a fan on the floor, could a good regular fan or circulating fan help cool the room more? Also, how should I tilt it to help with cooling?

Related, possibly duplicates: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/13671/6973 and https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/6881/6973

"I live in an area of high humidity." The larger the AC, the less frequently it runs, and the less effective it is at reducing humidity. A smaller AC might work better, in that case.

Place a fan on the floor near the AC unit, tilting it slightly upward. This helps to distribute the cool air more evenly throughout the room. Direct the fan towards the AC to spread the cold air more effectively. Additionally, consider using a dehumidifier to reduce humidity and improve cooling.

The perceived temperature (how it feels) and the real (measured) temperature are two different things. One of the most important factors affecting how we feel temperature is humidity - it makes us feel hot temperatures hotter and cold temperatures colder.
In your case, the things are quite simple - you have too much humidity. Just by removing humidity, you already feel better, even without the air conditioner.
So the first step I would recommend is to remove the humidity. Analyze the sources of humidity. If it is outside, then make sure it cannot get inside. Do not just close the windows, make sure that they actually insulate (do not allow any air flow). If the source is the bathroom, install a good ventilator in the bathroom (exhausting outside). If it is the kitchen, install a kitchen hood with exhaust outside (not recirculating). Possibly, even replace that blanket with a proper door (which properly closes on all sides).
Cooling a heavily used kitchen is quite a difficult task. So you might want to keep the kitchen warm, and the room cold. It would bring a lot more satisfaction long-term.

Make sure that the portable AC actually exhausts outside. if it exhausts inside, you will actually increase the temperature (overall), instead of lowering. Make sure that the hole in the wall (window) for the exhaust of the AV is properly filled (between wall and tube, so the hot air from outside cannot get inside. The exhaust tube of the AC should be as short as possible (inside) - easy to achieve if you place the AC unit really near the wall.
We had this situation in the office, when colleagues did not understand that AC units also create heat - on the other side. I had to take them (the colleagues) to feel the heat at the exhaust port with their hands, to understand that what we were doing was worse than useless. That changed the situation, and we did what I explained above.

If the kitchen and the living room are one room, and they cannot be physically separated, then things are less god, but still doable. The first thing to remember is that cooking can create more heat than the AC can manage. A kitchen hood will also exhaust cooled air. So overall, things could be solved like this:

keep the dehumidifier always ON (it must have some automatic setting, trying to keep a certain level of humidity);
make sure to empty the water tank of the dehumidifier regularly;
stop the AC while cooking;
use the good kitchen hood while cooking (reduce the humidity);
when the cooking is finished, start the AC, enjoy the food and the cooled air.

The other comments still stand, even in this situation.


Outside sunny or shady?  If the sun is hitting windows in these rooms, reducing the sunlight would make a difference.  You could add reflective plastic window film.  Have an awning attached to the house or use a large table umbrella.  Or hang something, like a tarp, over a window.

Inside, reduce cooking humidity, cover all pans, cook at lower heat, try alternate cooking methods than boiling...
Instead of using the full big oven, try using a combination of microwave and skillet.

About fans, the cool air will be on the floor, so you can move that more easily.  If there's a place above the room, you can let the heat rise up by opening a door.

If the home gets cool every morning, start the AC earlier, but if not, and the other tips can't be used, you will likely need to buy a larger air conditioner.  8,000 is basically good for a bedroom.  Off season, I see them for sale used.


Best to you in comfort and efficiency...
Jeff

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
